# 2 news sources that contradict in news esp. for political purposes

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Think of the news on North Korean National TV and the news presented in American news sources like CNN. My sentence is

> If you want to make sure of the credibility of a piece of news, that's a good idea to check it in ..... news sources or media.

Is *opposing* or maybe *opposite* a good choice of word? I assume I could say something like *the news sources of the opposing sides* but I'm interested in a word which conveys the meaning.

Comment: I wouldn't try to condense it into a single word. I'm thinking something more along the lines of: _If you want to make sure of the credibility of a piece of news, it's a good idea to check news sources **on both sides of the political spectrum**._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The news sources wouldn't be opposite. The news or opinions presented might be. So:

> If you want to make sure of the credibility of a piece of news, *then it's* a good idea to check it in **different** news sources or media. They may present an **opposing view** on this issue.

Also it is better to follow the if/then format.

Comment: But _different_ doesn't imply the news sources belonging to two opposing sides. CNN and BBC are also two different news agencies.

Comment: Just "opposing" might be the best choice, actually.

Comment: But the networks aren't opposing each other, unless that is clear in context.